# Mysql top 3 count values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have a query that returns following values:

```
TemplateCode    Total
    1418        35
    7419        31
    7418        31
    8325        17 
    15623       17
    4997        17
```

I want all the rows with top 3 `Total` values

In my query if I include `LIMIT 3` in the query then it gives only 3 which I don't want. I don't want to include `LIMIT` because count may vary from time to time.

How can I include condition on `Total` and always get top 3 count values

My current query is like:

```
select TemplateCode, count(*) as Total from table group by TemplateCode
order by Total desc
limit 3
```

Comment: `select * from table group by TemplateCode` Please do not use construction like that. [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: are you asking for getting the top 3 largest numbers ? if yes, then just use MAX() on your current query, this would give you the results you needs. (if that what you're asking for)

Comment: how can I use `max()` in the command?

Comment: What result set do you want?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.Total >= (select distinct t2.Total
                  from t t2
                  order by t2.Total desc
                  limit 2, 1
                 );
```

This assumes that you want the third *distinct* value.  If you just want the third value, remove the `distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a inner join on subquery for the top 3 total

```
select m.TemplateCode , m.total
from my_table m
inner join (
  select Total
  from my_table 
  order by Total Desc 
  limit 3
) t  on t.total = m.total 
 order by m.total, m.TemplateCode
```